# Create htaccess URL redirect to prepend "/content" to all URLs except the homepage in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I'm redesigning and migrating an old WordPress website that has a pretty standard URL structure:

- Homepage (`example.com`)
- posts (`example.com/someposts/`)
- archive Posts (`example.com/archiveposts/`)
- pages (`example.com/somepages/`)

For marketing reasons, I need to create a `.htaccess` 301 redirection or bouncing rule that "prepends" `/content/` routing to the whole website (EXCEPT the homepage). So the new URL structure should be like this:

- Homepage (`example.com`)
- posts (`example.com/content/someposts/`)
- archive Posts (`example.com/content/archiveposts/`)
- pages (`example.com/content/somepages/`)

In other words, the whole website (except the homepage) now should be 'inside' `/content/`.

Currently I have the standard WordPress routing `.htaccess` rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried different solutions but none of them worked, most of them just redirect some pages to another single one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the *top* of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker:

```
# Redirect all URLs to "/content/..." except the homepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ /content%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above states:

1. For any URL except the homepage (that does not match the regex `^(index\.php)?$`).
2. And the URL does not already start with `/content/` (by the preceding `RewriteCond` directive)
3. Then prefix `/content` to the start of the URL-path via an external redirect.

Any query string on the original request is naturally preserved.

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues. And clear your browser cache before testing since any earlier erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser.

Comment: thanks, i think we are in the right direction BUT i found two problems: if i click on any link on the homepage, the browser keeps bouncing when trying to go to the link. Also, all the theme assets (and the wp-admin) are redirected to /content/ now. I didn't clarify before but the redirection should only affect the public part of the website (except homepage) like pages / posts / archives / categories list etc, and not the theme uris or the /wp-admin, /wp-includes or /wp-content parts.
I'm following your suggestions testing first with 302, entering private mode and clearing the browser cache.

Comment: @Federico What do you mean by "bouncing"? I've updated my answer to include a filesystem check, so it won't redirect if the original request already maps to a file or directory.

Comment: your updated answer fixes the assets and wp-admin unintended redirection... great! But I still get the "link bouncing" problem. By "bouncing" i mean that after i click on any link on the homepage, the browser hangs up indefinitely when trying to go to the link, and the linked page never loads... it seems like the browser keeps on refreshing indefinitely.

Comment: @Federico Have you made sure the browser cache (and any intermediary caches) are cleared? What is the URL of the link you are clicking on? Do you get any error in the browser?

Comment: I have a bunch of browsers installed (Chrome, FF, FF Dev Ed, Safari) and the website doesnt have any cache plugins. I'm clicking a couple of links at the homepage, ex: 'example.local/cptarchive/', 'example.local/cpt/postname'. The console shows no errors but in the network tab i can see three lines, 1) Status 302, GET, http://example.local, file: /cpt/postname/ 2) No status, GET, http://example.local, file: /content/cpt/postname/ 3) No status, GET, http://example.local, file: /content/cpt/postname/ . At that point i have to stop the browser cause it keeps on refreshing indefinitely